# Tag tidy and synonym request

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

To tidy things up please

Rename [debian6](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian6) to [debian-6.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian-6.0) then synonym it to [debian-squeeze](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian-squeeze)

Synonym [debian-5.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian-5.0) to [debian-lenny](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian-lenny)

Synonym [lenny](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lenny) to [debian-lenny](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian-lenny)

Synonym [etch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/etch) to [debian-etch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian-etch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All cleaned up now. Nice and neat. Lenny and Etch were already synonyms.